# Is there a way with ESS (Emacs Speaks Statistics) to get the *R* buffer where commands are sent actually be persisted to disk?

Tags: r, emacs, ess

One of the advantages that Jupyter has these days when running with an R kernel seems to be the fact that your notebook command and output is saved. When I run `M-x R` from emacs to start up ESS I have an R console in a buffer to which I can also use `C-c C-r`, `C-c C-j`, and `C-c C-p` or `C-c C-b` to send commands to. This is very nice - but the buffer is temporary (like the scratch buffer). Is there a way for it to ideally append to a file so that one has a "notebook" archiving all session commands and their output?

Comment: If you want a notebook in emacs check out http://orgmode.org/, https://github.com/gregsexton/ob-ipython/, or https://github.com/millejoh/emacs-ipython-notebook

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can save the buffer just as you would any other buffer in emacs.

Comment: But how would you "resume" there after restarting R?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you mean "resume your R session" or do you mean "append some more output to the log of the previous session"?

Comment: Sorry, the latter is what I meant

Comment: I don't know of a way to open the file in inferior-ess-mode. However, you can start a new R session and append it to the existing file with `M-x append-to-file`.